# Polymer core-animation stopped working

Tags: animation, polymer

Hi i have recently updated polymer to 0.5.1 and my core-animation stopped working.

Here is my core-animation element:

```
<core-animation duration="400" fill="forwards" id="show">
  <core-animation-keyframe>
    <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="0.7"></core-animation-prop>
  </core-animation-keyframe>
</core-animation>
```

and js code:

```
var show = this.$.show;
show.target = this.$.img;
show.play()
```

The problem is that this doesn't work at all. In chrome console i get error `Uncaught #<Object>` which is caused by line 63 in effect.js:

```
61      if (group[0].offset != 0 || group[group.length - 1].offset != 1) {
62        throw {
63          type: DOMException.NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR,
64          name: 'NotSupportedError',
65          message: 'Partial keyframes are not supported'
66        };
67      }
```

Comment: You might need to import `web-animations-next/web-animations.html` in addition to `web-animations-js/web-animations.html` in order to get some animations working again. They added the `web-animations-next` directory in the latest update!

Comment: Nope, that's not an issue. I have tried with and without this imports with no effect.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like with 5.1, you need at least two keyframes, one for starting value and one for ending value.